# Aggregate and summarise dataset information with R

Tags: r, aggregate, summarize

I have a breeding productivity dataset:

```
df1
    # Nest.box Obs.type individual.number Clutch
    # 1 Nest1 Egg 1 First
    # 2 Nest1 Egg 2 First
    # 3 Nest1 Egg 3 First
    # 4 Nest2 Egg 1 First
    # 5 Nest2 Egg 2 First
    # 6 Nest2 Egg 1 First
    # 7 Nest1 Chick 1 First
    # 8 Nest1 Chick 2 First
    # 9 Nest2 Chick 1 First
    # 10 Nest2 Chick 2 First
    # 11 Nest2 Chick 1 Second
    # 12 Nest2 Chick 2 Second
```

I want to summarise these data by aggregating by **Nest.box** and **Clutch** (shows the max number of eggs, the max number of chicks by nest.box, by clutch)

The wanted output would be something like this:

```
output
        # Nest.box Clutch Eggs Chicks
        # 1 Nest1 First 3 2
        # 2 Nest2 First 2 2
        # 3 Nest2 Second NA 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can all be done within `tidyr::pivot_wider()` for data.frames:

```r
library(tidyr)

df1 %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = c(Nest.box, Clutch),
    names_from = Obs.type, 
    values_from = individual.number, 
    values_fn = max
  )
#> # A tibble: 3 × 4
#>   Nest.box Clutch   Egg Chick
#>   <chr>    <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 Nest1    First      3     2
#> 2 Nest2    First      2     2
#> 3 Nest2    Second    NA     2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

##### Data

```r
df1 <- 
  tibble::tribble(
    ~Nest.box, ~Obs.type, ~individual.number, ~Clutch,
    "Nest1", "Egg", 1, "First",
    "Nest1", "Egg", 2, "First",
    "Nest1", "Egg", 3, "First",
    "Nest2", "Egg", 1, "First",
    "Nest2", "Egg", 2, "First",
    "Nest2", "Egg", 1, "First",
    "Nest1", "Chick", 1, "First",
    "Nest1", "Chick", 2, "First",
    "Nest2", "Chick", 1, "First",
    "Nest2", "Chick", 2, "First",
    "Nest2", "Chick", 1, "Second",
    "Nest2", "Chick", 2, "Second"
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

Tidyverse approach would be

```
df %>% group_by(Nest.box, Clutch, Obs.type) %>% 
  summarise(max = max(individual.number)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = 1:2, names_from = Obs.type, values_from = max)

# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   Nest.box, Clutch [3]
  Nest.box Clutch Chick   Egg
  <chr>    <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>
1 Nest1    First      2     3
2 Nest2    First      2     2
3 Nest2    Second     2    NA
```

Answer (score 1):

`data.table` solution

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(Eggs = uniqueN(individual.number[Obs.type == "Egg"]),
              Chicks = uniqueN(individual.number[Obs.type == "Chick"])), 
          by = .(Nest.box, Clutch)]

#    Nest.box Clutch Eggs Chicks
# 1:    Nest1  First    3      2
# 2:    Nest2  First    2      2
# 3:    Nest2 Second    0      2
```

**edit**

also a possibility: casting to wide format

```
dcast(setDT(df), Nest.box + Clutch ~ Obs.type, value.var = "individual.number", fun.aggregate = uniqueN)
#    Nest.box Clutch Chick Egg
# 1:    Nest1  First     2   3
# 2:    Nest2  First     2   2
# 3:    Nest2 Second     2   0
```